# Property 'query' does not exist on type 'Request Nodejs and typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to add typescript to my existing nodejs project. On my controller i import express as following : `import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express"` and later on my code :

```
let reqQuery = { ...req.query };
// Typescript says that Property 'query' does not exist on type 'Request<any, any, any, any>'.ts(2339)
```

## UPDATE

This is the complete code, getProducts is a controller ("@types/express": "^4.17.6")

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from "express"
const getProducts = AsyncProvider( async 
(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    let reqQuery = { ...req.query };
    ....
})
...
module.exports = getProducts;
```

Could you helps me please?

Thank you

Comment: The code is right, you should add more context. Which @types/express version have you? How is `req` defined and where does it come from?

Comment: Hi, thank you, i updated the code to answer your question

Comment: I mean the post :)